# How to show different WordPress front page for logged out and logged in users?

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have a Wordpress membership site and its homepage explains how to sign up, etc.

I want to have a different homepage for people who already signed up/ are signed in so that they don't see this homepage since it only contains content pertaining to users who have not signed up.

I searched online but couldn't find a set answer to this question.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What plugin are you using to help you with your membership. S2Member and Ultimate Members and most other plugins have a feature that will allow you to redirect to a specific page once signed in. Keep in mind the ability to sign in or stay signed in also depends on your cache and cookies and most caches time out after a period of time. So if a user signed up and logged into and didn't log out but revists the site tomorrow they would more than likely have to sign back in again because their cache timed out after a period of time. (For most it about 7hours) but you can use a caching plugin to increase the time to days would should solve your problem for the most part.

Comment: I'm using Restrict Content Pro. I already have it so it redirects to a certain page when you sign in. What I am looking for is a different front page once you are signed in.

Comment: When you mean front page do you mean a user specific page i.e. private content page? If the user is signed in and is being redirected to a different page they wouldn't be seeing the front page right?

Comment: you could just add this to the header.php, at the very top before the <!DOCTYPE html>:

    <?php if(is_front_page()) {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $newURL = 'http://YourWebsiteURLhere.com';
        header('Location: '.$newURL);
    }
    } ?>
OR you can add this to Functions:

    function homepage_template_redirect()
    {
    if( is_front_page() && is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        wp_redirect(get_page_link('contact'));
        exit();
      }
   }
   add_action( 'template_redirect', 'homepage_template_redirect' );

Comment: if that doesn't work you could try this as well  add_action('init', 'my_redirector');

function my_redirector(){
    if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com/contact_us'); 
        exit;
    }
}

Comment: <?php if(is_front_page()) { if (is_user_logged_in()) { $newURL = 'YourWebsiteURLhere.com';; header('Location: '.$newURL); } } ?>

this worked! thank you so much!